# Relationship between sign(weight) and sign(gradient)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient

On the 4th page of the paper [Explaining and Harnessing Adversarial Examples](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6572.pdf),
There is a sentence starts with:

> Note that the sign of the gradient is just −sign(w), ...

But in case of y=-1, for me the sign of gradient looks like sign(w).
Could anyone explain the math behind this?